# Why is there a method called "overplot" in dot plots? What are the differences between jitter, overplot, and stack in dotplots?

Tags: r

So from research online, we generally avoid overplotting because it's difficult to visualize your data. Yet this is listed as one of the methods in dot plots/stripcharts. A followup question is what are the differences between the following methods for dotplots aside from aesthetics:jitter,stack, and overplot.

I tried to use the following code to see those differences, but aside from it's visual effects, I don't understand what exactly is going on. This is using the ToothGrowth Data set. Any help would be appreciated.

```
ToothGrowth1 <- ToothGrowth
 par(mfrow = c(1,3))
stripchart(len ~ dose,data = ToothGrowth1, pch = 19, frame = FALSE,
  vertical = TRUE, method = "jitter")
stripchart(len ~ dose,data = ToothGrowth1, pch = 19, frame = FALSE,
  vertical = TRUE, method = "overplot")
stripchart(len ~ dose,data = ToothGrowth1, pch = 19, frame = FALSE,
  vertical = TRUE, method = "stack")
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

The documentation for `stripchart` states that "stripchart produces one dimensional scatter plots (or dot plots) of the given data. These plots are a good alternative to boxplots when sample sizes are small."

Overplot, overplots so you will only ever see one dot regardless of how many there are for a given value.

Jitter, jitters or applies a random displacement in the x axis so you may get a better impression of the number of observations or samples for a given point. Depends on the number of values and degree of jitter to apply with the `jitter` argument.

Stack, stacks the dots neatly so you can see all of them.

Overplot may be usefully combined with `alpha` argument when specifying colour with `rgb` function, this enables you to distinguish number of points by the density of the colour produced by overplotting. See second graph

```r
df = data.frame(a = rep(1:5, 1:5))


par(mfrow = c(1,3))
stripchart(df, pch = 19, cex = 3, frame = FALSE,
           vertical = TRUE, method = "overplot", main = "Overplot")
stripchart(df, pch = 19, cex = 3, frame = FALSE,
           vertical = TRUE, method = "jitter", jitter = 0.5,  main = "Jitter")
stripchart(df, pch = 19, cex = 3, frame = FALSE,
           vertical = TRUE, method = "stack", main = "Stack")
```

[image]

#### overplotting with `alpha`

```r
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
stripchart(df, pch = 19, cex = 3, col = rgb(0, 0, 0), frame = FALSE,
           vertical = TRUE, method = "overplot", main = "Overplot")
stripchart(df, pch = 19, cex = 3, col = rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.1), frame = FALSE,
           vertical = TRUE, method = "overplot", main = "Overplot with alpha")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I've updated the answer to provide a  possible approach to using overplot. If it answers your question it is customary to click the accept tick and upvote if you have sufficient reputation.